# How can I get the string with more lowercase characters from a given List?

Tags: java, while-loop, java-stream

How can I get the string with more lowercase characters from a given `List<String>`?

I've already done it in a functional way, using Java 10 Streams, but I want to do it in an iterative way, using `while` loops. But I have no idea how to do it. 
This is my functional code.

```
public static Optional<String> stringSearched (List<String> pl) {
   return pl.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(x->x.chars()
                                       .filter(Character::iLowerCase)
                                       .count()
            ));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Well, I tried to do it with Lists and foreach loop, and from this, use a while loop. But I am in the Engineering Dregee, so teachers want the exercise just as they do it, and I get stucked. Last year we used it Java 8 Streams and I am very confident with then, but we did not study while loops in depth.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Something {
    public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("LOSER");
        list.add("wInner");
        list.add("sECONDpLACE");

        System.out.println(findMoreLowerCase(list));
    }

    private static String findMoreLowerCase(final List<String> list){
        String moreLowerCase = ""; // Tracks the current string with less lowercase
        int nrOfLowerCase=0; // Tracks the nr of lowercase for that string

        int current; // Used in the for loop
        for(String word: list){
            current = countLowerCase(word);
            if(current > nrOfLowerCase){
                // Found a string with more lowercase, update
                nrOfLowerCase = current;
                moreLowerCase = word;
            }
        }
        return moreLowerCase;
    }

    private static int countLowerCase(String s){
        // Scroll each character and count 
        int result = 0;
        for (char letter : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(letter)){
                ++result;
            };
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: That way is very intuitive, but I need to code it with while loops. I´ll see if I can do it from this code. Thank you so much, very helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, I just read "loops". Anyway, it should be trivial moving from for loops to while loops, and it can help you understand it better. Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: No problem! I will try by my own anyways. Like I said, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, if you manage to solve please consider marking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to be to iterate over all your words and replace non lower case letters (with a regular expression such as [^a-z]) with empty strings, and then get the length of the string.

The longest string is the one that has the most lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String moreLowerCase(final List<String> stringList) {
  String moreLowerCase = "";
  final Iterator<String> iterator = stringList.iterator();

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final String current = iterator.next().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
    if (current.length() > moreLowerCase.length())
      moreLowerCase = current;
    }
return moreLowerCase;
}
```